# MobileFirst adapter endpoint not visible

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have a MobileFirst adapter with multiple GET and POST-methods/endpoints, they are located in the AdapternameResource.java file and they follow the standard of:

```
@GET
@PATH("/name")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response method()
{
}
```

They are all visible when i view the adapter in MobileFirst Console.

Now i added a new get method that just returns a hello world-object, however this method is not visible in the MobileFirst Console and i cannot call it.

I added the method to the resource file, do i need to do something more??

Comment: Will be easier if you'll upload the adapter... and also mention your mfp version...

Comment: Just to confirm - after making changes the adapter was built and redeployed?

Answer (score 0):

As Vivin mentioned, it does sound like you forgot to build and/or deploy the adapter after adding this fifth endpoint.

```
mfpdev adapter build  
mfpdev adapter deploy
```